# HTTP GET request can't get

Tags: http, .htaccess, get, hosting, request

When I try to send a HTTP request like

`GET /`
I can't reach to index.html or index.php. 
The host brings the page `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`.

When I try `GET /index.html`
This time i get a 404 not found error. It says `(none)/index.html` not found.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `index.html` in the web root. The server has been configured to redirect requests for `/` to `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` instead, and you should honor that.

Comment: That's not what the web server says.

Comment: Have you considered that you may have a server configuration issue instead?

Comment: Yes I considered, but the problem is configuring it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that `DocumentRoot` in the `httpd.conf` file is pointing to a different directory instead of where your `index.html` is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, check if you set your [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) value in `httpd.conf` correct. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem until looked at my page via anonymous access service (like [this](http://eu.amnotseen.com/)). Actually the problem was with my DNS cache.